# Arm Linux sshd-telnetd Kernel Oops Tracking

Tags: linux, arm, kernel

I have an ARM-Linux Embedded system with Allwinner A20 CPU. It runs Debian Wheezy 7 with sunxi kernel 3.4.79.

I am getting this error in every a few days, totally random:
    https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8-UCj5FQ1cVUXZYTEFQU1dRalU/view?usp=sharing

If you see clearly, the issue seems to be caused from SSHD or TELNETD, however I think it is hiding the real trouble. I am using exactly same eMMC image over hundreds of identical devices without any trouble.

For testing,

```
1) Disabled all kernel modules -> no luck.
2) Reduced CPU clock to 528Mhz - > No luck
3) Replaced power supply -> No luck
4) Replaced hardware -> No luck
```

How can I trace this issue, and how can I find out the real reason of this oops ?

Note: The embedded system is running Asterisk 1.8.13.1 with 435 SIP Clients.

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Unix tech support is on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to move the question...

Answer (score 1):

To trace linux oops you can use gdb with vmlinux image.
For example, read this manual
http://opensourceforu.com/2011/01/understanding-a-kernel-oops/